# Method to find the height of list of widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I was trying to find the heights of individual widget in listview. Method I followed is as followed-

1. Make a list of global keys and assign it to individual container widget.
2. Then use this function [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOhqD.png)
3. It is giving me error that currentContext is not defined [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igwJU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `GlobalKey` and template it depending on the state it is holding if this is the case.

```
// If you are holding a statefulWidget
final myKey = GlobalKey<YourState>();

// else
final myKey = GlobalKey();
...
RenderBox renderBox = myKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
```

You can also use the `LayoutBuilder` to wrap your child widget with and get their height.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid code calculateHeight() fill fix ur problem.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: SizedBox(
        key: _key,
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
      ),
    ));
  }

  double calculateHeight() {
    final renderObject = _key.currentContext?.findRenderObject();
    if (renderObject == null) return 0;
    if (renderObject is! RenderBox) return 0;
    return renderObject.size.height;
  }
}
```